# Loop and return value with q

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

I am trying to find the best way to loop through an array, perform an operation on every element of the array and return the result using `Q`.

Let's say I have this array:

```
var q = require('q');
var arr = [1, '2', "3", "undefined", undefined];
var values = [];

q.fcall(
   function(){
     arr.forEach(d){
        if (d){
           values.push(1);
        }
        else{
          values.push(0);
        }
     }
     return values;
   }
 ).then(
  function(v){
    v.forEach(d){
    console.log(d);
  }
 });
```

Comment: Is this javascript? Is this node.js?

Comment: exactly it is nodejs

Comment: What does nodejs have to do with this?

Comment: What is `q`? You haven't defined it in the code you supplied. You should provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the operation you perform is not asynchronous you can just use regular [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and resolve the mapped array:

```
var operationFunction = function(d) {
  return d ? 1 : 0;
};

q(arr.map(operationFunction)).then(function(v) {
  v.forEach(function(d) {
    console.log(d);
  });
});
```

If your operation is a node.js style asynchronous function you can map the source array to an array of promises, and then wait for them to resolve:

```
var operationFunction = function(d, done) {
  process.nextTick(function() {
    done(null, d ? 1 : 0);
  });
};

var wrapperFunction = function(d) {
  return q.nfcall(operationFunction, d);
};

q.all(arr.map(wrapperFunction)).then(function(v) {
  v.forEach(function(d) {
    console.log(d);
  });
});
```

Or, if the operation function is asynchronous and you can edit it you could use deferred objects:

```
var operationFunction = function(d) {
  var deferred = q.defer();
  process.nextTick(function() {
    deferred.resolve(d ? 1 : 0);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
};

q.all(arr.map(operationFunction)).then(function(v) {
  v.forEach(function(d) {
    console.log(d);
  });
});
```